# Is it possible to work with Doctrine, Twig and PHPUnit in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, doctrine, phpunit, twig

I wonder whether is possible to use CodIgniter with the benefits they bring other frameworks, such as. Symphony.

Is it possible to use in this framework Doctrine, the system templates and Twig PHPUnit?

Comment: sure, it's possible to use doctrine & twig within code-igniter and also to integrate symphony to code-igniter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.

Doctrine, Twig and PHPUnit are stand alone components and you can use them without working with Symfony as base framework.

You can certainly configure/use them with CodeIgniter.